# Clojure PostgreSQL JDBC keep getting error executing query

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, clojure

i hope someone could help me with this,

So i'm building database backed website with clojure and postgresql,
but i keep getting error.
Here are the code and error on REPL:

```
(ns app.config-postgre
  (require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]))

(def db1
  {:classname "org.postgresql.Driver"
   :subprotocol "postgresql"
   :subname "//localhost:5432/dbname"
   :username "username"
   :password "password}) 
;;that's not the real username and password, the real one is right
```

here goes the code that caused error :

```
(sql/insert! db1 :user123
             {:username "user" :password "pass" :user-id "1"})
;;PSQLException ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 43  org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse (QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
```

and

```
(sql/execute! db1 ["INSERT INTO user123 VALUES ('{\"user\", \"pass\" ,1}')"])
;;PSQLException ERROR: null value in column "password" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains ({user,pass,1}, null, null).  org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse (QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
```

and

```
(sql/execute! db1 ["INSERT INTO user123 VALUES ('{\"user\"},{\"pass\"},{1}')"])
;;PSQLException ERROR: malformed array literal: "{"user"},{"pass"},{1}"
  Detail: Junk after closing right brace.
  Position: 29  org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse (QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
```

and

```
(sql/execute! db1 ["INSERT INTO user123 VALUES ('\"user\",\"pass\",1')"])
;;PSQLException ERROR: malformed array literal: ""user","pass",1"
  Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
  Position: 29  org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse (QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
```

and

```
(sql/execute! db1 ["INSERT INTO user123 VALUES ('user','pass',1)"])
;;PSQLException ERROR: malformed array literal: "user"
  Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
  Position: 29  org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse (QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
```

Any suggestion?
Thank you in advance

edit schema for table user123 :

```
CREATE TABLE user123
(
  username character varying(100)[] NOT NULL,
  password character varying(100)[] NOT NULL,
  "user-id" integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("user-id")
)
```

Comment: What's the schema for the `user123` table?

Comment: @schaueho CREATE TABLE user123
(
  username character varying(100)[] NOT NULL,
  password character varying(100)[] NOT NULL,
  "user-id" integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("user-id")
)

Comment: Your attempts look reasonable to me, the only thing that comes to my head is that maybe the "user-id" column name might cause some confusion. Have you tried with a different value than "user" for the username parameter to rule out that it's not barfing on the "user-id"? Otherwise, try specifying the loglevel property of the postgresql driver, maybe this will give you more information. See the documentation on `sql/get-connection`, this should be possible with the DriverManager approach.

Comment: i'm no database expert, but it appears to me that you are specifying `username` as an array of variable (but bounded) length strings - you probably, unless you are intending to have several user names per row, do not mean this. i would drop the `[]` from the definition and try again. same with password.

Answer (score 1):

Use `(sql/execute! db1 ["INSERT INTO user123 VALUES (?, ?, ?)" "user" "pass" 1])` for your purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
(sql/execute! db1 ["INSERT INTO user123 VALUES ({'user'}, {'pass'}, 1);"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your should change **:username** to :**user** in your db specification.